# auto tabbing script wont work on wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

this is probably something silly - i'm not a coder so i'm just trying a simple copy and paste of a function i need.

its this that i want : 
http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qygB2/4/

```
$(function() {
var charLimit = 1;
$(".inputs").keydown(function(e) {

    var keys = [8, 9, /*16, 17, 18,*/ 19, 20, 27, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 46, 144, 145];

    if (e.which == 8 && this.value.length == 0) {
        $(this).prev('.inputs').focus();
    } else if ($.inArray(e.which, keys) >= 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (this.value.length >= charLimit) {
        $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
        return false;
    } else if (e.shiftKey || e.which <= 48 || e.which >= 58) {
        return false;
    }
}).keyup (function () {
    if (this.value.length >= charLimit) {
        $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

it works great on there.

now - if i literally copy and paste it verbatim into my wordpress page it just fails.

here is live on a test site

http://bangforbuck.co.uk/111-2/

so i've copied this onto the wordpress page:

```
<input class="inputs" type="text" class="inputs" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" class="inputs" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" class="inputs" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" class="inputs" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" class="inputs" />
<input class="inputs" type="text" class="inputs" />
```

and the above js into an "insert script to head" plugin.

now the autotab fails to work....so i'm thinking i've got something basic, foundation, wrong?

thanks for your time.

nick

Answer (score 0):

The Auto-Tabing JS code already works for input fields which are below the "Check Numbers" button. But Only difference is "id" of all input fields which are above the "Check Numbers" button are different.

So, If you want to keep both input fields which are above and below the "Check Numbers" button then please include below mentioned code snippet into your page or else if you want to keep only input fields which are  above the "Check Numbers" button then use below JS code instead of your JS code:

```
$(function() {
    var charLimit = 1;
    $(".inputs").keydown(function(e) {

        var keys = [8, 9, /*16, 17, 18,*/ 19, 20, 27, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 46, 144, 145];

        if (e.which == 8 && this.value.length == 0) {
            if (this.id=="n2"){
              $('#n1').focus();
            }else
            if (this.id=="n3"){
              $('#n2').focus();
            }else
           if (this.id=="n4"){
              $('#n3').focus();
            }else
            if (this.id=="n5"){
              $('#n4').focus();
            }else
           if (this.id=="n6"){
              $('#n5').focus();
            };
        } else if ($.inArray(e.which, keys) >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (this.value.length >= charLimit) {
            if (this.id=="n1"){
              $('#n2').focus();
            }else
            if (this.id=="n2"){
              $('#n3').focus();
            }else
           if (this.id=="n3"){
              $('#n4').focus();
            }else
            if (this.id=="n4"){
              $('#n5').focus();
            }else
           if (this.id=="n5"){
              $('#n6').focus();
            }else
           if (this.id=="n6"){
              $('#n7').focus();
            };
            return false;
        } else if (e.shiftKey || e.which <= 48 || e.which >= 58) {
            return false;
        }
    }).keyup (function () {
        if (this.value.length >= charLimit) {
            if (this.id=="n1"){
              $('#n2').focus();
            }else
            if (this.id=="n2"){
              $('#n3').focus();
            }else
           if (this.id=="n3"){
              $('#n4').focus();
            }else
            if (this.id=="n4"){
              $('#n5').focus();
            }else
           if (this.id=="n5"){
              $('#n6').focus();
            }else
           if (this.id=="n6"){
              $('#n7').focus();
            };
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```